# Javascript RegExp does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

The parameter *return_value* contains

```
   <textarea>{"id":43,"description":"","item_id":28,"callback":"addNewAttachment","filename":"foo.jpg",,"type":"posts","ext":"jpg","size":145}</textarea>
```

The next code removes the *textarea* tags in Firefox, Chrome, so the content can be accessed in arr[1]. In IE alert("Failure") is called.

```
function addAttachment(returned_value) {
    var re = new RegExp ("<textarea>(.+)</textarea>");      
    var arr = re.exec(returned_value);
    if(arr != null && arr.length > 1) {
        var json = eval('(' + arr[1] +')');
    } else {
        alert("Failure");           
    }   
    window[json.callback](json);
}
```

*returned_value* comes from an ajax call. I use JQuery.

**TEST**

This does not work either:

```
var re = new RegExp (/<textarea>(.+)<\/textarea>/);
```

**SOLUTION**

The problem was that IE was getting the textarea String uppercased while firefox was getting it lowercase.

The next regular expression solves it.

```
var re = new RegExp ('<textarea>(.+)</textarea)>','i');
```

Comment: did u try 'var re = new RegExp (/<textarea>(.+)</textarea>/);'

Comment: You say *Variable \*return_value\* contains* but you have `re.exec(returned_value);` in the code. Is this a typo in the question text or your code?

Comment: @palindrom: If you use /.../ it's already a RegExp object, you shouldn't create a new RegExp object from it...

Comment: To make it more readable you can also use the case insensitive flag as other mentioned: 
    new RegExp(..., 'i')

Answer (score 4):

Is this a case-sensitive issue?  `new RegExp(..., "i")` might help?

Comment: BTW.  Just noticed the JSON object contains two commans: ",," - I think IE will barf on that in the eval() once you get that far.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a regex literal:

```
var r = /<textarea>(.+)<\/textarea>/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

What IE version do you use? I tested the following code in IE 7 and it worked:

```
<script>
var x = '<textarea>{"id":43,"description":"","item_id":28,"callback":"addNewAttachment","filename":"foo.jpg",,"type":"posts","ext":"jpg","size":145}</textarea>'

var r = new RegExp('<textarea>(.+)</textarea>');
var a = r.exec(x);
for (var i=1; i<a.length; i++)
    alert(a[i]);
</script>
```

**Edit**: I checked with this code in IE7 and it also works. *test.xml* is a file that contains the string and sits in the folder next to the HTML page with the script. I assume it should also work with a dynamic page that returns the same thing.

```
<script>
function test(x) {
    var r = new RegExp("<textarea>(.+)</textarea>");
    var a = r.exec(x);
    for (var i=1; i<a.length; i++)
        alert(a[i]);
}

var rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
rq.open("GET", "test.xml", false);
rq.send(null);
test(rq.responseText)
</script>
```

Comment: You are right, the code works when returned_value is in a string. But I am getting the value returned by the server in an ajax call and there seems to be the issue. Any idea?

Comment: What kind of Ajax framework do you use? How is your call made?